# Node Voltage Analysis (diamond like circuit)

Tags: dc

Consider this circuit:

[image]

If we do node voltage analysis at Node A (assuming all currents go out we get)

$$ \frac{V-10}{2R} + \frac{V}{2R} + \frac{V}{2R} + i_1 =0$$

$$ \frac{3V}{2R} - \frac{10}{2R} = -i_1$$

$$ \frac{-1}{2R} (3V-10) = i_1 $$

Now this is where my problem is, I am having trouble expressing i_1 in terms of voltage difference because there is no resistor! I think I might have to use a supernode but I am not quite sure.

Comment: Isn't node A at 5 V? (assuming bottom line is ground)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A method that also gives good result is redrawing the sketch in a simpler form as shown below:

[image]

Current \$i_3\$ is the sum of \$i_2\$ and \$i_1\$ and equals:

\$\frac{10-5}{2R}=\frac{5}{R}+i_1\$

Solving for \$i_1\$ gives \$i_1=-\frac{2.5}{R}\$. As pointed out by jonk, considering the negative sign, the 5-V generator sources \$i_1\$.

Answer (score 1):

You could avoid nodal analysis. You already know all of the node voltages. Assuming ground where I placed it here:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fw8uTim.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Then \$V_1=10\:\textrm{V}\$, \$V_2=5\:\textrm{V}\$, \$V_3=2.5\:\textrm{V}\$, and \$V_4=2.5\:\textrm{V}\$. You should be able to compute:

$$\begin{align*}I_2&=I_4-I_1-I_3\\\\&=\frac{10\:\textrm{V}-5\:\textrm{V}}{2 R}-\frac{5\:\textrm{V}}{R+R}-\frac{5\:\textrm{V}}{R+R}\\\\&=\frac{10\:\textrm{V}-5\:\textrm{V}-5\:\textrm{V}-5\:\textrm{V}}{2 R}\\\\&=-\frac{2.5\:\textrm{V}}{R}\end{align*}$$

And I'm sure that's not so hard. Note, of course, that the negative sign means that the arrow I used was pointed wrong and that \$I_2\$ actually goes into node \$N_2\$.

---

But let's take this as nodal analysis and go by rote machinations. I'll assume that all currents from voltage sources are positive when leaving the (+) node and negative if entering the (+) node.

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{V_1}{2 R}&=I_{V_1}+\frac{V_2}{2 R}\tag{$N_1$}\\\\
\frac{V_2}{R}+\frac{V_2}{R}+\frac{V_2}{2 R}&=I_{V_2}+\frac{V_1}{2 R}+\frac{V_3}{R}+\frac{V_4}{R}\tag{$N_2$}\\\\
\frac{V_3}{R}+\frac{V_3}{R} &=\frac{V_2}{R}+\frac{0\:\textrm{V}}{R}\tag{$N_3$}\\\\
\frac{V_4}{R}+\frac{V_4}{R} &=\frac{V_2}{R}+\frac{0\:\textrm{V}}{R}\tag{$N_4$}
\end{align*}$$

In the above, I put all the "outflowing" currents on the left side and all the "inflowing" currents on the right side. Resistors "spill" in both directions (and therefore have a net current) so they appear on both sides. A voltage source's current is either flowing inward or else flowing outward, but not both, so it will only appear on one side or the other. Just be consistent, that's all. (This is the approach that software I've seen from Berkeley Spice handles the equation set up, by the way.)

Now, this is four equations. One for each of the nodes (other than ground.) It's done by rote. There should be, if we are lucky, four unknowns. And since we know that \$V_1=10\:\textrm{V}\$ and that \$V_2=5\:\textrm{V}\$, then it turns out that we do have four unknowns: \$V_3\$, \$V_4\$, \$I_{V_1}\$ and \$I_{V_2}\$. (Or, we could just add those two equations and have six equations and six unknowns.)

So plug that into your favorite solver and one of those resulting solution values will be the value you seek.

I'll use Sage:

```
sage: var('R V1 V2 V3 V4 IV1 IV2')
sage: q1=Eq(V1/(2*R),IV1+V2/(2*R))
sage: q2=Eq(V2/R+V2/R+V2/(2*R),IV2+V1/(2*R)+V3/R+V4/R)
sage: q3=Eq(V3/R+V3/R,V2/R+0/R)
sage: q4=Eq(V4/R+V4/R,V2/R+0/R)
sage: solve([q1,q2,q3,q4],IV1,IV2,V3,V4)
{V4: V2/2, IV2: (-V1 + 3*V2)/(2*R), V3: V2/2, IV1: (V1 - V2)/(2*R)}
```

Not so hard. So the answer is: \$I_{V_2}=\frac{3 V_2-V_1}{2 R}=\frac{2.5\:\textrm{V}}{R}\$. And since this is positive, it means that the direction of the current is in the assumed direction I made in writing out these equations and is therefore in the opposite direction to the green arrow I showed in the diagram at the top. In short, \$V_2\$ is sourcing current into the node \$N_2\$ and is not sinking current from it.

---

Nodal analysis "just works." You just need to be able to write up the equations quickly, one by one. But it can often involve more algebra than other approaches.